# Count the number of different column values on every day

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
`tasks` (`id`, `url_id`, `task`, `date`)
```

`task` can get values: 1, 2, 3. `date` is a unix timestamp. how do get a data saying how many tasks where performed on everyday where `url_id` = 1. The expected result is:

```
{`count_task_1`: 30, `count_task_2`: 14, `count_task_3`: 30, `date`='2011-03-12'}, [..]
```

Something like this will give me the number of all entries on that day for the `url_id`=1:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `tasks` WHERE `url_id`=1 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`));
```

The only options I see: multiple queries or sub queries (which are pretty much the same).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to `jink` for helping me to solve this question.

```
SELECT `task`, COUNT(`id`) `count`, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) `date` FROM `tasks` WHERE `url_id`=3 GROUP BY `task`, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`));
```

Comment: You are way off the mark. This doesn't even give the columns asked for. You haven't "solved" anything: the question is asking for a *pivot*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this high-performance trick for *pivoting* on different values:

```
SELECT
    SUM(task_id = 1) as count_task_1,
    SUM(task_id = 2) as count_task_2,
    SUM(task_id = 3) as count_task_3,
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) as date
FROM tasks
WHERE url_id=1
GROUP BY 4;
```

This works because `true` in mysql (and many other dbs) is `1` and `false` is `0`, so the `SUM()` of a condition is the count of it being `true`.